# Embed Power BI content using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, angular, powerbi, embedding

I'm trying to do the demo given iby Microsoft (https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master), trying to embed a report using the NodeJs. For this I'm using the MasterUser and I used all the values correctly in the config.json and add logs to check if I was getting the access token. This was all Ok until I tested and was facing this error message:

Error Details:

Error while retrieving report embed details

Unauthorized

What can be causing this error?

Comment: What API are you calling when you get that error?  Is your master user a workspace admin?  Does it work if the master user is _you_?

Comment: For this demo, I think I m calling the Power BI API. I created logs and I get those tokens but m still getting the Unauthorized error. This is also my first time trying to integrate reports into webpages in a secure way without using Power BI Embedding.

In terms of the workspace I m not the admin but I created the app in Azure AD and asked for the permissions and same in Power BI. This was just to try the demo to check if there was a way of embedding reports in webpages in a secure way

Comment: You said you were using a Master User.  That’s different from an App Registration Service Principal.  And what do you mean by “without using Power BI Embedding”?

Comment: For this Demo, I was trying to use only Power BI Pro and Azure AD. Trying to check ways to embed reports securely in angular and using NodeJs APIs